# If time is denoted by an imaginary number, what does that mean?

Tags: kinematics, time, projectile, complex-numbers

Suppose, the initial velocity of a car is 1m/s, acceleration 2m/s^2, distance travelled (-8)m. What is the time required to reach that distance? This is the first question.

The answer of the first question will be an imaginary number. But we know time can only flow in one direction. If we consider past time, then we will get negative value. Now what does an imaginary number mean in this case of time? This is the main question.

Comment: How do you get an imaginary number? And what do you mean by the negative sign for distance traveled?

Comment: Actually, the solution to the equation is not "the square root of a negative number" (i.e., a pure imaginary number.) The equation has two solutions, neither of which is purely real nor purely imaginary. If I did the math right (Ha ha!) They are approximately $=−0.25+1.96$ and $=−0.25-1.96$

Comment: @Arafat You still did not show your work and did not explain what is the minus sign doing in front of the displacement.  If both velocity and acceleration are in whatever you call positive direction, the displacement cannot be in the negative direction.

Comment: Exactly. This displacement can not be negative in real life. But I have shown you guys that, whenever this type of unrealistic attempt is done in math, we need to encounter imaginary number. As we have input unrealistic value in the math, the math as an output provided the imaginary number. I hope you got the thing.

Comment: Re: "whenever this type of unrealistic attempt is done in math, we need to encounter imaginary number." Not necessarily true. Sometimes when we ask an unrealistic question we get an unrealistic _real_ answer. "Complex" does not mean "unphysical." The fact that your equation has complex solutions is irrelevant. You aren't supposed to go there. We only measure time intervals with _real_ numbers. If your equation has no _real_ solution, it doesn't mean something magic is happening. It only means that the question you asked has no answer.

Comment: Not necessarily true, Solomon. There may be complex number as a result of math. But they are still considered answer. If you solve cubic equation, you will find a lot of irrelevant answer as you mentioned, but still they are taken as complex answer.

Comment: Re, "...but they are still considered answer..." May I refer you again to John Doty's answer? He said, "The math can't tell you, you must understand the physics." If you think that the existence of complex solutions to your equation means that the car can travel minus eight meters in some complex amount of time, then you don't understand the physics—Not completely. Not yet.

Comment: About the car incidence, obviously using negative distance does not make any sense. Thats what I have written in my answer and have depicted the absurdity of i.

Comment: Negative distance makes _perfect_ sense in a one-dimensional kinematics problem. If positive distance means distance measured in one direction (e.g., from the car to some point that can be seen out the front window of the car), then negative distance means distance measured in the opposite direction (e.g., looking out the back window.) There _is_ a point that is eight meters behind the initial location of the car. But the lack of any real solution to your equation means that within the time interval when that equation accurately gives the location of the car, the car is never at that point.

Comment: Re, "I have...depicted the absurdity of $i$." You certainly have prompted others to try persuade _you_ of the absurdity of trying to interpret a complex number as a measure of time. But if you hope that your arguments will stop physicists and engineers from using complex math in their calculations... Only time will tell.

Comment: Ok, you got the timing of car, partly. Now associate i with the timing and you will get the complete picture. Try my answer for easier understanding.

Comment: The comment you wrote regarding i is your misunderstanding. I am not promoting anything. Just logically judging what i mean in real sense as we use it in Copenhagen interpretation like probability amplitude. You know we are physicist. So we need to understand it.

Comment: What do you mean "Now associate $i$ with the timing?" Sorry? I thought _you_ were the one who asked, "what does an imaginary number mean _in this case_ of time?" You keep saying it's absurd. OK. I agree. _in this case_ it's absurd. It's absurd to look for meaning in the complex solutions to your equation. If there's any meaning to be found, it's in the _lack_ of any real solution. But I've already said that. No point in continuing to go 'round in circles. Have a nice life!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes when you get a complex result from a physics calculation, that means "it can't happen". Sometimes it means that something else happens, like an oscillation rather than an expected decay. Which is it? The math can't tell you, you must understand the physics.

Answer (score -5):

Yes surely we know this problem will yield an imaginary number and what actually this mean, we are going to find that.

Basically, this problem does not have any answer. Mathematics is a perfect model, which can describe a physical system and it does not matter whether the solution is logical or not. It is tit for tat. The thing you input in your equation, the output will be the exact aftermath.

Here we have input the value of displacement as the negative 8 meter, which physically impossible considering the mentioned system. So, math result has also become an impossible one, the square root of a negative number, which is commonly known as imaginary number.

So does it mean, imaginary number mean an impossible solution? Exactly but it means something more. It means in your math, the information required to solve the math are not completed. As we lack in information about the system, we can not get a proper real solution.

So what was the lacking info in the given question? That lacking information can be anything. Such as if you say that, when the car started moving, another big car collided against the direction of the first one and so our first car started going to the opposite direction and eventually crossed (-8) meter. If you add this type of information in your math, then the system is comprehensible and then we can do the math without making a sweat about the imaginary number.

Ok nice answer. But does that mean all the math that we have done so far using imaginary number (or simply call it 'i') are wrong? The answer is not all of them. But how? Ok, if we solve cubic equation using Tartaglia or Cardano formula, then we will find a lot of cases where we can cancel out those i, and then what remains will be real number. I guess, here you will not find any problem with that. Of course, there will be many cases where you will not be able to cancel all the i, those all are imaginary, absurd and don't have any solution. But remember any cubic equation with real coefficients will always have at least one real solution.

Then what about Schrodinger equation and all other electrical problems? The specialists on those subjects can tell you about that. But I will just say, when we are doing current-voltage related math; remember they are just approximation. They are not any perfect value. The parallel circuit and other stuffs and formula are just a model to find an answer mathematically and they are not any practical real value like the math you do in velocity, time and in other classical mechanics.

Sometimes this i is useful for telling you a sequence. Such as sine graph. This thing can be nicely described in terms of i because of its rotational property. Here notice that you can understand the value of -1 and 1. But the meaning of i and i^3 refers something impossible, right? So this must be wrong somewhere. Is that what you are thinking? See this is a function. In case of function, what you input does not matter, you just do the math accurately and you will get the correct solution. Using impossible for getting possible, isn't it fascinating? Nobody will tell you this secret. But now you know all the strategy regarding i, that they use in math; be it probability amplitude or any kind of quantum physics.

Though we can do the math manipulating i by the use of function, we are loosing the understanding of math. But see nobody cares about understanding if you get your solution done. Use rigorous proof or trick, that does not matter as long as your solution is correct. Remember,  math is a model. This model always being updated by discovering new ideas and as a physicist we always try to use those new ideas in solving our problem. What if our solution is wrong? We will continuously keep looking for new tricks to solve our problems at any cost. Because physicist is not about  being honest but about being successful in explaining the universe.

Comment: Re, "Here we have input...which physically impossible...So, math result has also become an impossible one..." The square root of a negative number is _not_ an impossible result. In fact, $t=-0.25+1.96i$ and $t=-0.25-1.96i$ both are actual solutions to OP's problem. What is impossible is assigning any _physical meaning_ to those solutions. Like @JohnDoty said, You have to understand the physics to understand what the solutions to the equation actually mean (if they mean anything at all.)

Comment: I agree with the part that we need to understand physics. But understanding physics requires understanding physical meaning. If we dont understand i, then how can we understand the solution? And if we dont understand the solution its pointless to understand physics.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re, "The parallel circuit and other stuffs and formula are just a model to find an answer mathematically and they are not any practical real value like the math you do in velocity, time and in other classical mechanics." The physical laws that describe the behavior of electronic circuits have every bit as much practical real value as the physical laws of kinematics. The physical laws of kinematics are nothing more than a model to find an answer mathematically.

Comment: Current, voltage these all are concepts for facilitating math use. Current is still an unsolved mystery. We just use it for our math calculation. On the other hand kinematics is perfect. If you know the conditions of a system, does not matter initial or final, you can accurately describe the whole system.

Comment: Re, "if we don't understand $i$..." Who doesn't understand $i$? It's really very simple. $i$ and $-i$ are distinct members of the set of complex numbers. The complex numbers, _by definition,_ obey all of the same algebraic rules as the Real numbers obey, and $i$ and $-i$, _by definition,_ are the two solutions to the complex equation $z^2+1=0$. Given that information, you can deduce literally everything else there is to know about complex math.

Comment: Where does definition comes from? It comes from understanding. You understand something, then you describe it. That is definition. But there may be prejudice in one's thinking. Thats why one needs to judge his thinking style also. You are giving me definition of i but what actually i is? Show me one real life example, where we can understand i.

Comment: This question is closed and it shows that it needs details or clarity. Well, regarding that, in my original question, I mentioned the math problem. Then I clearly stated that, it needs to solve imaginary number and  my question was what that meant. I think I have clarified my question and also I think further explanation is unnecessary. But still if anyone has any problem in understanding, please mention them in the comment and I will edit my question.

Comment: Re, "Where does definition comes from?" TLDR: In the 15th century, mathematicians found a formula that could be used to solve some special case cubic equations. But it had a flaw: For _some_ cubics that could be shown to have real solutions, the formula required taking the square root of a negative number. Some clever scholar wondered, what would happen if we _imagined_ that $\sqrt{-1}$ was a number. Long story short: He tried it, and the "imaginary" numbers cancelled out, and the formula yielded the correct real solution to the cubic. Other mathematicians took it from there.

Comment: Thats how i was embraced in mathematics. But still we dont know the meaning of square root of minus one, even if we know how it behaves. Do you suggest me anything to edit?

Comment: Re, "we don't know the meaning of square root of minus one" You keep saying that. If you're confused about what it means for your example to yield a complex time interval, It means that there's _something wrong with the question that you asked._ We do not use complex numbers to represent time intervals. We only use real numbers for that. If there is no _real_ solution to the equation, then it means that the question that you asked has no answer. The fact that your equation has complex solutions is irrelevant. You aren't supposed to look for a complex solution. That's not how the model works.

Comment: If you want another example of the kind of problem that we _do_ model with complex numbers, try this on for size: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform (Be prepared for some hairy math!)

Comment: Math is not just sticking to a model. It is about applying new discovery into action. Thus we get a lot of idea about what the new thing mean. You said time does not depend on i and we dont use the model of i in time. Here is the misunderstanding. If really i has a real meaning, you can apply it in any case like the way you use positive and negative sign. But as you said it is irrelevant to use the i in some cases, so that proves it has its flaws. That is what I have explained in my answer. You can suggest me anything regarding my answer.

Comment: If we consider using abstract math what we dont understand as irrelevant; then white hole, worm hole, time travel and other things will be also irrelevant. In fact it is the irrelevant math that brings new idea in physics and thats how we discover new model.